# Local preview of draft posts does not work

Tags: r, preview, blogdown

I tried to reproduce (and understand) Appendix [C.3 Building a website for local](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/local-preview.html) preview of the blogdown book:

I have demonized the server successfully in my `~/.Rprofile` with

```
options(servr.daemon = TRUE)
```

- Whenever I run `blogdown::serve_site()` those markdown files (.md) which are marked with `draft: yes` in their yaml-header do not appear at http://127.0.0.1:4321/ (or whatever the address of the local server is). If I change to `draft: no` they do appear. But in my understanding, all files should appear on the local website.
- If i  build the site with the menu 'Build Website' via GitHub and Netlify the `draft: yes` posts do not appear (= correct behavior)
- If I use `hugo -D` from the terminal, everything works as expected; `draft: yes' file do appear! But this works (as anticipated) only with .md files (not with .Rmd files).

At the moment I have to change the draft status every time I want to inspect the file locally with the danger that I forget to set it back to `draft: yes` and publish those files inadvertently on my live site.

So how can I see and edit `draft: yes` files on the local server?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? I cannot reproduce this issue with the default site created via `blogdown::new_site()` (I added `draft: yes` to both .Rmd and .md, and `serve_site()` shows draft posts as expected).

Comment: Sorry, that I didn't think to check with the default site. You are right - it works! So it has to be a issue with the hugo-academic theme: I installed the hugo-academic theme from scratch again and I had the same problem.

Comment: I tested the hugo-academic theme and I still cannot reproduce the issue: `serve_site()` does show draft posts. It is weird because `hugo -D` worked for you, and essentially `serve_site()` calls `hugo -D`: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/45860c7760f5ff8280feec73b45a31cc9accaf21/R/hugo.R#L31 Could you provide a reproducible example? Also check `blogdown::hugo_version()`; if it is not the latest version, try `blogdown::update_hugo()`: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/installation.html

Comment: I was working with hugo version 0.27, but maybe my RStudio version is a problem? I use the preview Version 1.1.353. Another maybe related issue: Sometimes I get after `blogdown:::serve_site()` the warning: `Not found:
./"/"` in the viewer pane.-- Reproducible example comes tomorrow.

Comment: blogdown should work with any version of RStudio. I'm also using Hugo 0.27, with blogdown 0.1.

Comment: I am working with blogdown 0.1 too.

Comment: Reproducible Example: https://github.com/petzi53/test-academic-theme. After the new install, I just changed baseurl, title,  added ignoreFiles and a new post "draft: yes.md".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **blogdown** 0.1 and your example at https://github.com/petzi53/test-academic-theme, I had to remove the comment after `baseurl` in config.toml, i.e., change

```
baseurl = "/"  # End your URL with a `/` trailing slash.
```

to

```
baseurl = "/"
```

Then I ran `blogdown::serve_site()`, and I can see the draft post:

[image: site preview]

The issue with comments has been fixed in the development version of **blogdown** [on Github](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown).

Comment: Yep! What should I do with this 'answer'? To accept it as the right solution? Or to wait until you have changed it?

Comment: If removing the comment solves your problem, you can accept the answer (I'll tweak it a little bit).